# SQL - WHERE clause with multiple AND and NOT IN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to return values not in FocusRegion Canada, but I still want to see all the values from the other FocusRegion's. (But if you are in Australia then you need to have a FirstPurchaseDate <= 2001-11-19 21:39:12.000)

This is my code and cant get it to work.

```
SELECT FocusRegion, FirstPurchasedDate 
FROM TabelName
WHERE FocusRegion NOT IN ('Canada') 
AND (FocusRegion NOT IN ('Australia') AND FirstPurchasedDate <= '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000')
```

Comment: `WHERE FocusRegion NOT IN ('Canada') 
AND (FocusRegion NOT IN ('Australia') OR FirstPurchasedDate <= '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000')` I guess

Comment: I'm guessing @OndřejŠotek 's comment is what you're getting at, but your question is not clear. Can you give an example data set or explain in words exactly which records you do and don't want?

Comment: @OndřejŠotek is correct!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `X IN (Y)`? Just use `X != Y`. Here's your query:

```
SELECT FocusRegion, FirstPurchasedDate 
FROM TabelName
WHERE FocusRegion != 'Canada'
AND (FocusRegion != 'Australia' 
  OR FirstPurchasedDate <= '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000')
```

Comment: with less negatives: `WHERE FocusRegion <> 'Canada' OR (FocusRegion = 'Australia' AND FirstPurchasedDate <= '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000')`

Comment: @whytheq yes, your version is easier to read. I used `!=` is more closely match OP's query (rather than totally rewriting the logic).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use `OR` instead of `AND`, because when you using `AND` you say *It should be not from Australia and having date <= 2001-11-19*, what is wrong for you, you should use It in following:

```
SELECT FocusRegion, FirstPurchasedDate 
FROM TabelName
WHERE FocusRegion NOT IN ('Canada') 
AND (FocusRegion NOT IN ('Australia') OR FirstPurchasedDate <= '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely worth using the `NOT` operator.

You don't want anything where it is in Australia and `> '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000'`

```
SELECT FocusRegion, FirstPurchasedDate 
FROM TableName
WHERE FocusRegion <> 'Canada'
  AND NOT (FocusRegion = 'Australia' AND FirstPurchasedDate > '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier to read - and more closely reflects the logic you detail in your question's description:

```
SELECT FocusRegion, FirstPurchasedDate 
FROM   TabelName
WHERE 
       FocusRegion <> 'Canada' 
       OR 
          (
            FocusRegion = 'Australia' AND 
            FirstPurchasedDate <= '2001-11-19 21:39:12.000'
          );
```